# Canvas don't save

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need your help with this function in my script.

```
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
Captura.addEventListener("click", function () {

    if (video.srcObject && video.srcObject.active) {
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        video.style.display = "none";
        canvas.style.display = "block";
        Captura.style.display = "none";
        TomarOtra.style.display = "inline-block";
        //let foto = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);
        var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1);
        var base64Data = dataUrl.split(",")[1]; 
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "/Formularios_campos/GuardarFoto");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.send("imagen=" + encodeURIComponent(base64Data));
    } else {
        errorMsgElement.innerHTML = "No se ha otorgado permiso para acceder a la cámara";
    }
});
```

And this is in my controller.

```
 [HttpPost]

        public ActionResult GuardarFoto(string imagen)
        {
            byte[] imagenBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imagen);

            string carpeta = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/";

            string nombreArchivo = "miImagen.jpg";

            string rutaArchivo = Path.Combine(carpeta, nombreArchivo);

            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(rutaArchivo, imagenBytes);

            return Json(new { success = true });
        }
```

I need to save the photo in the specified path. Everything runs, but when I enter the controller to save it, nothing is saved and no error is thrown. Can someone help me troubleshoot this? Thank you.